# UIImage passing between controllers causes memory warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app that takes an image from the photo library using UIPickerController and then loads it into an UIImageView in the first controller. Then i pass the UIImage **via property** to the second controller of navigation controller in order to **edit** the image here. When i **pop** this EditController tapping on **Back** and then retake the process passing one more time the image to the EditController, the memory encreases every time and after 5 cycles i receive memory warnings. Is there a solution to this issue?

```
 //Getting the image from the PickerController 
    _imageToEdit = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    _imageToEdit=[self fixOrientation:_imageToEdit];
    [_imageView setImage:_imageToEdit];

//Passing image to EditController
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editImage"]) {    
    EditImageViewController *destViewController=segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.newlyImage=_imageToEdit;
    destViewController.optVC=self;
    destViewController.numberReceived=_firstTimeInEdit;
}
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Echoing @nburk  It sounds like you have a retain cycle in your code somewhere, but without actually seeing any of it we can only guess.

Comment: Most likely you're creating a new copy of your edit controller each time, but not releasing the earlier version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new method where I release all the objects I don't need. I don't receive memory warnings anymore.

```
- (void) backAction {
[_editBaseController removeAllButtons];
_editBaseController = nil;
_undoImage = nil;
copyImage = nil;
_modifiedImage = nil;
_newlyImage = nil;
aCIImage = nil;
context = nil;
free(imageRawData);
free(filterChannelRowData);
_scrollingViewOne = nil;
_scrollingViewTwo = nil;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

Comment: One year later, your solution was to go 2012-style.
I guess there is some irony in this world.

Comment: In that controller I was working on image processing which you probably know that at some point you have to free memory ''by hand''